# Explanation of the ending of "A Quiet Place"

Tags: ending, a-quiet-place

I have just watched the horror a Quiet Place. Not at all bad. But I have a question concerning the end of the movie. Can anybody explain to me in what the tool against the aliens rest. To tell the truth I did not notice that the daughter is deaf. Does her handicap have something to do with the fact that it was she that came up with the effective defense?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does her handicap have something to do with the fact that it was she
>   that came up with the effective defense?

YES

Lee Abbott was constantly working on a hearing aid to help Regan to hear better so that she wouldn't get into trouble with the creatures due to her handicap.

Turns out the implant may not work as intended, but it has a much more potent effect — it emits a frequency that’s not only irritating to the creatures and their amplified hearing, it’s downright harmful. Whenever one of them gets too close to her, the ringing starts and the creature scampers off. The sound is unpleasant to her, but unbearable for the monsters and that fact saves her life more than once throughout the film.

In the end, she figures this out which, in turn, helps in killing the creature